# How to convert an Integer to a String in V8?

Tags: c++, v8

I have the following V8 code:

```
Local<String> getSumString(int32_t a,  int32_t b){
    int32_t sum = a + b;
    return String::Concat(String::New("The sum is: ") , String::New(sum));
}
```

In the above function I want to add `a` and `b`, then want to return a string "The sum is: CALCULATED_SUM " .

I'm having problems in converting the calculated sum to a String so that it can be concatenated with other String.

Comment: This doesn't look like JavaScript.

Comment: @Andy It's V8 source code - it has to _work_ with JavaScript directly, it's C++.

Comment: OP - is there any reason you're not just doing this with JavaScript directly?

Comment: Just a proof of concept… trying to check how can it be done in v8

Answer (score 0):

You don't say the nature of the error, but I'm guessing that the end of your output string is mangled, because you're instantiating a String from an int. V8 is interpreting that data as const char * data. You should instantiate an Integer from your int. Your last line will look like this instead:

```
return String::Concat(String::New("The sum is: ") , Integer::New(sum));
```